# Individual user settings in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, user-input

I have a webpage where user can show/hide a table columns if a button is clicked. What is the best method to store these changes and load them if the page reloads? On desktop application I usually use .ini or .xml but i'm still learning Razor Pages, and I don't know if something here also exists or not.

Thank You,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if the user's data is not very big, I suggest you could try to store them into the local storage or cookie. When you user access the site again, you could read it and use it by using js or jquery to keep the column show or hide.

Cookies:

An HTTP cookie (web cookie, browser cookie) is a small piece of data that a server sends to the user's web browser. The browser may store it and send it back with later requests to the same server.

About how to use cookie you could refer to this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_cookie.asp).

Local storages:

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Web storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

About how to use local storage you could refer to this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).